# How to never get Model without relationships in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I know, that I can fetch Model data based on their relationship existence using `with()` or `doesntHave()` in Laravel (9), but I never ever want to fetch Model data without a relationship, thus it is annoying to always write the `with()` function in all CRUD functions.

Is there a way to pre-filter models without a relationship directly in the Model class?

Adding `protected $with = ['foo'];` adds the relationships to every record, but is still including the ones without a relationship.

As an optional bonus to that: Maybe a bypass is nice to have, so that in general all results will have relationship but maybe for one specific path `GET /all_data` the pre-selection would be bypassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable `eager loading by default` if you add the relationship to the `$with` property of the model as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default

The documentation reads:

> Sometimes you might want to always load some relationships when
> retrieving a model. To accomplish this, you may define a $with
> property on the model:

=====Edit1 
Another option is using `Global Scopes` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#global-scopes.
You can go from here, you can add some more logic to exclude models without the relationship.
=====Edit2 
The extra logic will be adding this from the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```
protected static function boot(){
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope('relation', function($builder){
            $builder->has('relation')->with('relation');
        });
}
```

Comment: This is forcing to always load the relationships but it is loading the ones without relationships as well, as it runs the `'select * from foo where foo.deleted_at is null'` first and then the `select * from bar where bar.foo_id in (1, 2, 3)`. The result will have nullable relationships. I am searching for a solution to exclude all results without a null relationship

Comment: Can you elaborate why null values are problematic in your case? 
You could create a global scope, i edit my answer.

Comment: This is doing the exact same thing. Getting all relationships, but still includes all records, that don't have a relationship

Comment: @PeterPan as I wrote, you can go from there and you simply need to add some more logic.
You could add a whereHas() or whatever works in your case. I am not at a computer nor am I willing to do all of your work. All of the information given above was widely available in a simple google search, if you aren't able to complement the above code fragment you should consider hiring someone to do the work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking too much. But "add some more logic" es exactly for what I am asking for, as I don't know how to realise that. In my original question I already mentioned, that I know the `with()` function and all you suggest, is putting this function that I already know in different places but this function is not the solution to my problem. I googled and read the documentation before I asked. I am asking for the "extra logic" as this is what I don't know how to realise.

Comment: @PeterPan I added some more to the snippet. I hope this helps you.

Comment: That's it! Even the `with()` is not needed anymore. Thank you!